# Win32: How to make popup window match monitor DPI

Tags: winapi, dpi-aware

I'm working on a Win32 app with multiple windows, some of which use `WS_POPUPWINDOW` style (no caption) and some of which use `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` style. The app has System DPI awareness.

When I move the overlapped windows between monitors, they scale to match the current monitor DPI as expected. But the popup windows only do this if there are no other open overlapped windows. Otherwise, they always try to match the scaling of the last active overlapped window in the same process, even if it's on another monitor with a different scale factor.

I guess this makes sense for some use cases, since you'd always want eg. a popup menu to match the scale of the current window. But I want my popups to behave as independent windows with their own scale factor.

How do I make popup windows always match the DPI of the monitor that they're positioned on?

Comment: If you want per-monitor DPI awareness, make your application per-monitor DPI aware ([High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows) tells you how).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged

Comment: To be clear I'm not trying to fix the blurry/stretchy window scaling. I'm trying to fix what scale factor Windows decides to use for each window. It normally should scale to match whatever monitor the window is positioned on, but for popup windows specifically it doesn't work this way.

Comment: As @HansPassant linked, *The current DPI for a window always equals the last DPI sent by **WM_DPICHANGED***. In order to fix what scale factor Windows decides to use for these window, you need to handle this message correctly.

Comment: Are your popup windows independed or owned ones?

Comment: @DanielSęk They are independent. This only seems to make a difference if the owner is an overlapped window. For now I've given them an owner but made it invisible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix before I eventually convert the app to per-monitor DPI awareness, I created an invisible overlapped owner window for the popup that tracks its position / size. This ensures that whenever the popup is active, it updates to use its owner's scaling, which always matches the current monitor.